# Migration fails during update to 3.7.7

Tags: migration, updates, updating

I'm updating a Craft installation from 3.5.17.1 to 3.7.7 and it's failing when applying migrations.

I'm trying to do the update via CLI on MAMP. Here is the relevant part of the error:

```
*** applying m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets
    > add column sortOrder smallint UNSIGNED AFTER `fieldLayoutId` to table {{%globalsets}} ... done (time: 0.218s)
    > create index craft_idx_zmzquajmdqbiodivatcrahhtnuknzdbmqnmm on {{%globalsets}} (sortOrder) ... done (time: 0.085s)
Exception: Undefined index: name (/Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Globals.php:335)
#0 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Globals.php(335): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/Users/sites/mysite...', 335, Array)
#1 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1668): craft\services\Globals->handleChangedGlobalSet(Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#2 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1189): craft\console\Application->craft\base\{closure}(Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#3 [internal function]: craft\services\ProjectConfig->handleChangeEvent(Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#4 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(628): call_user_func(Array, Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#5 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(752): yii\base\Component->trigger('updateItem', Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#6 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1179): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_processConfigChangesInternal('globalSets.7c9f...')
#7 [internal function]: craft\services\ProjectConfig->handleChangeEvent(Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#8 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(628): call_user_func(Array, Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#9 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(749): yii\base\Component->trigger('addItem', Object(craft\events\ConfigEvent))
#10 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(521): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_processConfigChangesInternal('globalSets.7c9f...', true, NULL)
#11 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets.php(38): craft\services\ProjectConfig->set('globalSets.7c9f...', 7)
#12 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Migration.php(52): craft\migrations\m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets->safeUp()
#13 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(744): craft\db\Migration->up()
#14 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(379): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateUp('m210613_145522_...')
#15 [internal function]: craft\console\controllers\MigrateController->actionAll()
#16 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#18 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(184): yii\base\Controller->runAction('all', Array)
#19 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\console\Controller->runAction('all', Array)
#20 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/all', Array)
#21 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(89): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/all', Array)
#22 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): craft\console\Application->runAction('migrate/all', Array)
#23 /Users//sites/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\console\Request))
#24 /Users//sites/mysite/craft(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#25 {main}
*** failed to apply m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets (time: 1.955s)
```

Comment: Going to go ahead and vote to close this on SE, but you can read up on it here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/9660